# Replace Console.WriteLine in NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nunit

I haven't done much with NUnit before, but I just wanted to dump some text to a window in a console type fashion. For example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("... some information...");
```

That won't work of course because NUnit is driving things.

I'm in the middle of building some unit tests and want to dump a list of variable values for inspection during debug. It isn't strictly a unit test if I need to do this, I admit that, but it would be convenient.

Comment: For one of the answers, it is the same as in *[How do I get nunit3-console to output my debug to screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405753/how-do-i-get-nunit3-console-to-output-my-debug-to-screen-on-a-windows-box)* - *"in NUnit 3, you should use TestContext.WriteLine(...) in your tests"*. It [works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405753/how-do-i-get-nunit3-console-to-output-my-debug-to-screen-on-a-windows-box#comment110657051_46407376) as well.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can see the console output. You just have to select the "Text Output" tab in the NUnit GUI runner.

[image]

If you are using the ReSharper test runner, the console output should be displayed. Ensure that the test runner output window is displayed by clicking the ["Show Output" button](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Sessions.html#showOutputRow-1-td-0-control) in the test runner tool bar:

[image]

You should then get something as follows:

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.  I now realise that I need to have nunit installed.  Currently it is running via an assembly reference that came with the project, and I think resharper has hooks into it.

Comment: @sgtz Are you running your NUnit tests via the ReSharper test runner? If so, the output should be in the output window of the test runner. Please see my update.

Answer (score 77):

In NUnit v3, you can also write to the test results output for debugging with

```
TestContext.Out.WriteLine("Message to write to log");
```

Comment: This is the type of functionality I was looking for. Works in Debug *and* Release. Visual Studio 2017(15.8.7)

Comment: Even better is TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(string) for continuous output to the Output window of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I don't get anything in output window when running a unit test nor in the output log

Comment: Or, even shorter [`TestContext.Write(...)`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#write) and [`TestContext.WriteLine(...)`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#writeline).

Comment: Where the output will show in VS Code?

Comment: I'm not sure on VS Code,  this was focused on Visual Studio's. However, you may check the Test Explorer log. That might have it, or some similar option.

Answer (score 36):

Try using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` instead.

Comment: This applied only in Debug Mode. In Release Mode it's not working.

Comment: ``System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine`` will output in release builds as well.

Answer (score 15):

In Visual Studio 2017, in the `Test Explorer` window, there is a link, `Output`, in the lower `Test` pane. This brings up anything written to the console during that unit test.

Comment: Nop, nothing there for me, nothing of my writeline content at least

Answer (score 9):

Use the Test-Output view.

Steps:

1. Open Test Explorer
2. Select any particular test
3. Run it if it has never been run.
4. Click on the **output** link on the test results pane.

There is no need to replace `Console.WriteLine` with anything as this view logs messages from:

> Console.WriteLine
>
> Trace.WriteLine
>
> Debug.WriteLine
>
> TestExplorer.Out.WriteLine

[image]

Comment: This is only applicable for failing tests, how about for passing tests?

Comment: @Mark I see it for passing tests too. Maybe your issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Is "Test-Output" literal?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No. As highlighted in the screenshot, it is the **output** button inside the view where test's output/results are displayed.